# How to query a remote MS ACCESS .mdb database using C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to use C# to query a mote MS ACCESS database .mdb file. I can successfully query it when copying the file to my local machine. I just want to put the file remotely, so my the client side program doesn't contain raw data.

```
static string m_path = "http://www.xyz.com/temp/";
static string m_connWords = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " + m_path + "data.mdb";
```

I skip the rest of code doing connection, reader, and query.

I am sure when I have my m_path change to a local path for a local mdb copy, it works. And I can download the mdb file when using the url path, so the url path is specified correctly. Anyone know how what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to an access database via HTTP. You'll need to access it via a file share UNC (\server\share\access.mdb).

Comment: Hi Lynn, the issue is that the server is locked within a secure domain and only authorized users (I am one of them) can access its file system. The server has a apache webser for website hosting. And I am thinking about utilizing the http web server for doing this. I don't not have enough privilege to configure the server. I am not sure what I should do.

Comment: I mispoke. You can apparenly hit an access db via http by using RDS (although I have never used it.) According to connectionstrings.com, connection string would look something like: Provider=MS Remote;Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Remote Server=http://server.adress.com;Data Source=d:\myPath\myDatabase.mdf

Comment: Additionally, you'll need to configure IIS for this. See MSKB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q253580/

Comment: Not really sure how to get around that issue of only have apache, and not having IIS, or access to configure the server. At this point, I'd start looking at a different solution.

Comment: My best idea would be to switch over to a non-file based database solution (SQL Server Express comes to mind), and load the data into it. That way, you're not opening the entire file across the connection, just a socket for sending a query and receiving data. Unfortunately, access databases were never designed to be shared across WAN-type connections.

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to some FTP upload n download temporary for that....

see this link

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SimpleFTPDemo.aspx

and when you put it in temp directory you got then local path.. of MS Access

```
OR
```

Open your "Client Panel" of website and make ODBC Driver/MS Access Database in that...
see the information about how to connect Database MS Access in your SitePanel.

you can see there all the informations like 
How to...
Mail Client Settings, MS Access Database Connection, MS SQL Database Connection,
just for example in my domain panel i have this on ZNetPanel...
[image]

[image]

And then i think you knw how to connect ODBC !!

Comment: I don't think that will be a good idea. The thing is the mdb file I have is very big

Comment: see my edited answer.. dnt forget to vote me.. and accept answer.. dud..!! :)