# Connect web form to external Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to connect a website form to an external Microsoft Access database.  The website and database are on different servers. The website is going through a hosting company and the database is located inside a company office network.

My goal is to have users fill out an online form and then that information will be sent and saved to the Access database.

Is there a tutorial on this or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The Access Database would need to reside somewhere on the same server as the website is hosted. Also, there are known limitations of using MS Access such as the number of requests that can access the Access database at the same time. I would suggest looking in to using SQL Express and if needed export the data to a MS Access Database when needed

Answer (score 0):

**TODO:** You'll need to change the path to the mdb (in the connection string), probably hook up to some button click event instead of form load, change the table name (tblYourData) and the field names (field1, field2, etc) in the sql string, and instead of using 'some text', use the .Text property of the textbox on the page.

```
protected void Form_Load()
{
    string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";
    string sql = "insert into tblYourData (field1, field2) values ('some text', 'some more text')";
    CreateCommand(sql, connstring);
}
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**--Edit #1 --**

This can only be done with the MDB is located on the same network (local hard drive, or network file share) as the IIS server.

Comment: I formatted this for you, but it won't compile as you have it now.

Comment: Sorry, was in the middle of typing, but accidentally clicked "Post Answer". It's complete now.

Comment: How would this connect to an external server? The website and database are on different servers. The website is going through a hosting company and the database is located inside a company office network.

Comment: As a side note, ideally this should be a parameterized query for safety against an sql injection attack.

Comment: I didn't realize by 'external', you meant 'not on the same network'. In this case, this seems like a dupe question. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684474/how-to-query-a-remote-ms-access-mdb-database-using-c-sharp/5684484#5684484

Comment: Connecting to MS Access using SqlClient provider? Really?

Comment: Oh *#@!. Sorry @George. *smacks forehead*

Answer (score 0):

Considering this isn't possible, you have a couple of options.

Option 1:

1. Save it to a local database (sql express, sql server, etc...)
2. Allow them to set up a linked server between the access database and your database.

Option 2:

1. Save it to a local database (sql express, sql server, etc...)
2. Allow them to export the data to a CSV or similar format.
3. Then they can import that data into their Access database.