# How to connect to an Access 2003 database located on a web server via HTTP?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have a MS-Access 2003 located on (Http://SubDomain.DomanName.Com/Folder1/mydb.mdb) and Visual Basic 6.0 ..... how to establish connection..

im just a registered user on the host domain with sub-domain and full access to the (Folder1) Directory ....

How to connect to this (Path) .

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684474/how-to-query-a-remote-ms-access-mdb-database-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Jet is an embedded database technology.  The database engine runs in-process and needs full file I/O access to the MDB, LDB, and MDW files involved.

There is the possibility of using [Remote Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this is an "unconnected" model of access, basically a sort of Web Service.  A 3rd party hosting provider would be very unlikely to provision this service or give you the ability to yourself.

Instead you'll probably have to design and implement some sort of Web Service or otherwise run a middle tier on the server instead.

Comment: ok, you mean that i will need to develop some sort of middle solution to accomplish this ?! and there is no direct solution ?!

Comment: Depending on what you are doing you could send SQL and get back XML, ADTG-format serialized Recordsets, CSV, almost anything.

Comment: I'll store the connection string and my database info into the XML file uploaded on the web server, and will send/retrieve values in/from the XML file while working on the database.