# How to connect Delphi to remote MS Access Database through the internet?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, web-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect to an Access 2003 database located on a web server via HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167021/how-to-connect-to-an-access-2003-database-located-on-a-web-server-via-http)

I have a working Delphi program that uses a MS Access Database to obtain reports etc.
Now I want to migrate the database to a webserver running my website. The website must be able to connect to the database as well, to update data (users inserting contact details as an example).

How do I now connect my Delphi program to the database which is now on the webserver, without losing any functionality? Is this possible?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How were you connecting to the database before it moved to the web server?

Comment: I used an ADO connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the cases is to provide DB computer IP-address in ADOConnection.Connectionstring:

```
Data Source=X.X.X.X,Port
```

Answer (score 0):

If you migrating the Access database to the web, then are you talking about using the new web publishing feature of Access? For example, in the following video at the half way point I switch to running the Access database 100% in the browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Note that no Silverlight, or ActiveX downloads is required, and these published Access applications work in any web standard compliant browser – including safari on my iPad.

However, right now, if you are using Delphi to open that mdb file, keep in mind you are NOT connecting to that file, but simply opening a file.

I mean it is silly to say we connect to a word file, or we connect to a Power point file. So in the case of the office suite and those files, we are talking about plane Jane windows file.

A horse is a horse is a horse.

A file is a file is a file.

So you don't connect to the jpg file sitting on the hard drive, you OPEN the file. So if you talking about your current setup it best to use the correct terminology here. You are not connecting to that access file, but are in fact opening a plane Jane windows file. (if you look close at your connection string, it will ALWAYS have a fully qualified windows path name in it that resolves to a file sitting on a folder).

If you place such a file on a web server (as opposed to using the web publishing feature of Access), then you still faced with having to open that windows file. That means you need some kind of VPN and you also will need the windows file and network system in place (so this will mean you have to have samba running if this is Linux).

So you cannot open files through a web interface, and even as such when you use FTP or http, these are not real "windows" networking systems that allow you to open + use a plane Jane windows file.

While you thus in theory could extend windows network to the server with a VPN, it not a common setup and using a VPN over the internet is slow.

So as such, just keep in mind the concept that you are not really connecting to some file like power point or some mdb file sitting in a folder – you need to be able to OPEN the file, and you need to be using the windows networking system to do this open file in the case of Access. Access is in fact much more requiring of this open ability, since with Excel or Word, the file can be downloaded in whole from the server – with Access, the file is not downloaded in full, but requires a real working windows file open command before use.

So, one choice here would be to consider using the web publishing feature of Access, but the resulting published application on the sever will not be stored in a accDB or mdb file anymore – and from Delphi you can however use a set of web services that are exposed for the published Access site that would allow you to update the data – there is no oleDB provider, but there are web services, and also you can use linked tables from the desktop Access client to also connect to and edit the published Access web application.

Comment: Haha, sorry for the incorrect terminology, but you seemed to know exactly what I was talking about.

Thank you for your insight, it has given me something to think about and work off. Thank you very much, I appreciate it.